# Symbols as constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

There is no document that says a symbol cannot have a capital letter. As it makes for nice readability in my code to use symbols as strings, specifically constants I would like to do so. This works:

```
describe 'Stack Overflow' do
  let(:stack_overflow) { true }

  it 'Interpolation works' do
    puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{stack_overflow}"
  end
end

# >> Stack Overflow is helpful: true
```

This does not work:

```
describe 'Stack Overflow' do
  let(:STACK_OVERFLOW) { true }

  it 'Interplation does not work' do
    puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{STACK_OVERFLOW}"
  end
end

# >> NameError:
     uninitialized constant STACK_OVERFLOW
```

I can't figure out why I cannot use a capital letter in a symbol name (and get it to interpolate), or if the issue has more to do with using rspec's [`let`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L284).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` defines a method with the name you pass to it. So, in your first example, you define a method named `stack_overflow` and you call it in your string interpolation.

In your second example, you define a method named `STACK_OVERFLOW`, but you *do not* call that method! `STACK_OVERFLOW` is dereferencing a constant, if you want Ruby to treat it as a method call, you have to make it obvious that it is a method call by either adding a receiver or an argument list or both (since only method calls can have a receiver or an argument list):

```
puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{self.STACK_OVERFLOW}"
puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{STACK_OVERFLOW()}"
puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{self.STACK_OVERFLOW()}"
```

Answer (score 4):

RSpec's `let` defines a memoized helper method for use in your specs. By convention, method names that start with uppercased letters are treated as constants. So when you call `STACK_OVERFLOW`, Ruby attempts to look for a constant with that name - you can explicitly tell Ruby to invoke the method by appending parenthesis to it:

```
puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{ STACK_OVERFLOW() }"
```

Also, if you'd like to use constants in your specs, you can leverage RSpec's [`stub_const`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/mutating-constants):

```
describe 'Stack Overflow' do
  stub_const('STACK_OVERFLOW', true)

  it 'Interpolation should now work' do
    puts "Stack Overflow is helpful: #{ STACK_OVERFLOW }"
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful.   I want to give you and Jorg both credit for the answer,  but I had to pick one.  I went with his because I liked his explanation on the different ways to get around it.  Hopefully the community will help pick the better answer too.

Comment: @mdo123 thanks! I'm glad you found the answers helpful :)